# Accessing macro function for all documents

Tags: vba, macros, microsoft-word-2013

I have created a macro function as:

```
Sub updateFontCC()

Dim doc As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To doc.Range.Characters.Count

     If IsNumeric(doc.Range.Characters(i)) Then
        doc.Range.Characters(i).Font.Name = "Cambria"
        Else
        doc.Range.Characters(i).Font.Name = "Candara"
     End If
Next i

End Sub
```

which I want to use for each new document whenever I want to use it. Also I don't want to execute/run macro code again and again for each time whenever I need this macro.

How to access this macro function without executing it each time as I need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear what you mean by "*How to access this macro function without executing it each time as I need it*", but I think I understand what you are asking.

Put your code in the module section of `Normal` in the VBA Explorer's left pane.

[image]

This will make it available to all Word documents when they are open.

When you need it, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> to open the macros window. Choose the macro and click <kbd>Run</kbd>.

Comment: @CharlieRB--Thanks that's what I wanted :)